# Update VSCode to C++20

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code with C++20 with clangd.

Unfortunately it seems to be running in C++98.
I get the following error when using basic things like `std::function`
[image]

I have updated as many settings as I can see to C++20, and the `__cplusplus` macro now also says 2020. However this problem still persists.

I can compile without issues using: `g++ --std c++20 main.cpp -o main`

I am also missing a few `.json` files. I only have `tasks.json` in my `.vscode` folder.

Comment: You'll need to setup the cpp properties json if you want to configure intellisense, have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, but when I run `code .` it only opens VSCode and doesn't create the json files. I am missing both the c cpp properties and the compile commands files. I've also said I want to use clangd, not Intellisense

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The files aren't created automatically

Comment: I was able to create the c cpp properties file manually. However it doesn't have any effect on the version of C++ being used when I change "cppStandard". This is also the setup for IntelliSense which cannot be used because it conflicts with clangd

Comment: Have you followed the clangd [instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd)

Answer (score 0):

Clangd does not use c_cpp_properties.json for configuration, that file is specific to Microsoft's vscode-cpptools extension.

To configure your project for use with clangd, you need to follow the procedure described here: https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup